# Detect moment when newline starts in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I try to detect when carriage goes at new line in UITextView. I can detect it by comparison total later width with UITextView width:

```
CGSize size = [textView.text sizeWithAttributes:textView.typingAttributes];
if(size.width > textView.bounds.size.width)
      NSLog (@"New line");
```

But it dose not work proper way because `-sizeWithAttributes:textView` returns only width of letters without indentation width. Help please solve this.

Comment: Is this the standard `UITextView` you're using, or a subclassed version ?

Comment: Sorry, you want to know if the user presses "enter" while typing? Or you want to just count the total number of line breaks in the text?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

- Get the `UITextPosition` of the last character.
- Call `caretRectForPosition` on your `UITextView`.
- Create a `CGRect` variable and initially store `CGRectZero` in it.
- In your `textViewDidChange:` method, call `caretRectForPosition:` by passing the `UITextPosition`.
- Compare it with the current value stored in the `CGRect` variable. If the new y-origin of the caretRect is greater than the last one, it means a new line has been reached.

Sample code:

```
CGRect previousRect = CGRectZero;
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    UITextPosition* pos = yourTextView.endOfDocument;//explore others like beginningOfDocument if you want to customize the behaviour
    CGRect currentRect = [yourTextView caretRectForPosition:pos];

    if (currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y){
            //new line reached, write your code
        }
    previousRect = currentRect;

}
```

Also, you should read the documentation for `UITextInput` protocol reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput#/apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput). It is magical, I'm telling you.

Let me know if you have any other issues with this.

Comment: @mriddi. I have given you a skeletal structure. You will *have* to add conditions as per your need. For instance, editing code in the middle of your text, or replacing words or characters.

Comment: There are cases where this won't work. What about when the user pastes in text and the caret position is moved in the process?

Comment: Hence i mentioned that conditions *have to be added*.

Comment: Please can anybody help me with the following question? If the user writes bulleted text (multiple line breaks) in UITextView, how to detect the total number of line breaks?

Comment: Will this help if textView's text is set programmatically?

Comment: @NikhilManapure, sure. Just make sure you call the relevant code after you're done setting the text. Setting text programmatically does not call the delegate method (I think, though I'm unsure).

Answer (score 11):

answer of **@n00bProgrammer** in `Swift-4` with ***more precise*** line break detection.

**@n00bProgrammer** answer is perfect except one thing it reacts differently when the user starts typing in a first line, it presents that `Started New Line` too.
*Overcoming issue, here is the refined code*

```
    var previousRect = CGRect.zero
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let pos = textView.endOfDocument
        let currentRect = textView.caretRect(for: pos)
        self.previousRect = self.previousRect.origin.y == 0.0 ? currentRect : self.previousRect
        if currentRect.origin.y > self.previousRect.origin.y {
            //new line reached, write your code
            print("Started New Line")
        }
        self.previousRect = currentRect
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

For Swift use this

```
previousRect = CGRectZero

 func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        var pos = textView.endOfDocument
        var currentRect = textView.caretRectForPosition(pos)
        if(currentRect.origin.y > previousRect?.origin.y){
            //new line reached, write your code
        }
        previousRect = currentRect

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the UITextViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText: (NSString *)text
{
     BOOL newLine = [text isEqualToString:@"\n"];
     if(newLine)
     {
          NSLog(@"User started a new line");
     }
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is most elegant. The current accepted answer is very hacky.

Comment: This only works if user presses return key, not if the new line starts because it reached the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

The accepted answer and the swift version works fine, but here is a Swift 3 version for the lazy people out there.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
    var previousRect = CGRect.zero

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        textView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 20, 
            y: 0, 
            width: view.frame.width, 
            height: 50
        )
        textView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let pos = textView.endOfDocument
        let currentRect = textView.caretRect(for: pos)
        if previousRect != CGRect.zero {
            if currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y {
                print("new line")
            }
        }
        previousRect = currentRect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5**

Lets not overcomplicate things.

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if text == "\n" {
        // return pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4**

If you don't want to use previousRect. Let's try this:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let pos = textView.endOfDocument
    let currentRect = textView.caretRect(for: pos)
    if (currentRect.origin.y == -1 || currentRect.origin.y == CGFloat.infinity){
       print("Yeah!, I've gone to a new line") 
       //-1 for new line with a char, infinity is new line with a space
    }
}
```

Comment: in which case u get currentRect.origin.y == -1 ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the height of the text, not the width. Use either `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` (if you need to support iOS 6 or earlier) or use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` if you only support iOS 7.

Comment: Just IOS7. Plz more details about using second one

Comment: Look at the docs. It's similar to the `sizeWithAttributes:` method you were using. You just need to pass in a size. Pass in a size with the desired width and a really large height. The returned size will be the same with but with the needed height to fit the text in the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by layoutManager:

```
func findLineBreakPositions(in textView: UITextView) -> [Int] {
    guard let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager else {
        return []
    }

    var lineBreakPositions: [Int] = []
    let textStorage = textView.textStorage

    // Create a text container with the width of the UITextView
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: textView.bounds.size)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: textStorage.length)

    // Enumerate through the entire text and find line break locations
    layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: range) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, stop) in
        // Check if the line is broken
        if !usedRect.equalTo(rect) {
            // Find the character index corresponding to the line break
            let charIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: glyphRange.location)
            lineBreakPositions.append(charIndex)
        }
    }

    return lineBreakPositions
}
```