# Keyboard avoiding tableview with textviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with text views in each cell. How can I scroll the tableview so that the text being entered into a cell's textview is always visible? This is different from a tableview with textfields, because a textfield does not change it's height, while  textview does, if a new line is entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextView` changes its height each time return is pressed. Detect when return is pressed and scroll the `UITableView` slightly upwards.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        CGPoint currentOffset=myTableView.contentOffset;
        currentOffset.y-=10;
        [myTableview setContentOffset:currentOffset];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: But what if the user does not press return? Text is simply wrapped on to the next line

Comment: @BalázsVincze Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008713/detect-moment-when-newline-starts-in-uitextview

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare new variable
   UITextView *activeTextView;
2. In ViewDidLoad method, register the keyboard notification while show/hide.

   ```
   [self keyboardNotifications];
   ```
3. Add the following method.
       - (void)keyboardNotifications {
           // Register notification when the keyboard will be show
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                      object:nil];

   ```
       // Register notification when the keyboard will be hide
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
   }
   ```
4. Set UITextview tag using indexpath in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

   ```
    #pragma mark - Keyboard handling
   -(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
       if(activeTextView)
           if ([TableCell count] < activeTextView.tag) { // It is validate table cell count and activeTextView.tag
               NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
               CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

               UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
               tableV.contentInset = contentInsets;
               tableV.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
               [tableV scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:activeTextView.tag inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
           }
       }

   }

   -(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^(void) {
            tableV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            tableV.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }];
   }
   ```
5. UITextView delegate set as activeTextView with current UITextView.

   ```
   #pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate ::

   - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       return YES;
   }

   - (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       return YES;
   }

   // To be link with your TextView event "Editing Did Begin"
   //  memoryze the current TextView
   - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       activeTextView = textView;
       [textView becomeFirstResponder];
   }

   // To be link with your TextView event "Editing Did End"
   //  release current TextView
   - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       activeTextView = nil;
       [textView resignFirstResponder];
   }
   ```